# How I can use duration in spriteKit(swift)?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I create:

let wait = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 4.0)
run(wait)

but duration doesn't work as need

Comment: Hi Nick, please improve your question, is about Actions? Threads? What do you want to do? and how you are trying to do it? Make a clear example and a good explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost there. Replace "yournode" with the SKSpriteNode you want the wait action to apply to:

```
let wait = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 4.0)
yournode.run(wait)
```

Further, you can use it in a sequence.
e.g you run 1 action, wait 4 seconds, then run another action. You do this in the following way:

```
let move = SKAction.moveBy(x: 50.0, y: 80.0, duration: 2)
let wait = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 4.0)
let scaleup = SKAction.scale(to: 2.0, duration: 2)
let sequence = SKAction.sequence([move,wait,scaleup])
yournode.run(sequence)
```